# Setting up Bugzilla with hudson

Tags: hudson, bugzilla

Not sure if this is right place for this question but I'll ask anyways.

I'm trying to set up bugzilla with hudson but not sure how it works. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Could you expand the question? What exactly are you attempting to do? What have you tried and what is failing?

Comment: Not really sure how the two are supposed to work together. I thought that hudson would file bugs in bugzilla against the bugzilla product. Though so far I've only found the config in hudson which takes the url and login details for bugzilla. I haven't been able to find any tutorials on Hudson & Bugzilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug-in just gives you hyperlinks back to bugzilla based on commit comments. See http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Bugzilla+Plugin.
What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: My issue was that I didn't understand how the two worked together. Thanks for you help.